# Cycle takes too long

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

I have a code, and the problem is that the foreach cycle takes a very long time. For 100 accounts, it can take about 1 minute. This is due to the fact that every time I have to read the file, although this file is needed by all accounts.
I tried to read it once, but after one send it becomes unavailable for further sending, and I have to read it back for all remaining accounts.
Maybe you can somehow read it asynchronously to reduce the cycle time? Or, in general, how to make the file read once for all accounts?

```
            foreach (var account in CurrentToSendAccounts)
            {
                try
                {

                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(audioFile.FilePath))
                    {
                        await botClient.SendVoiceAsync(
                                    chatId: account.AccountID,
                                    voice: new InputOnlineFile(fileStream, fileStream.Name)
                                    ).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   
                }
            }
```

Comment: This may not be the root problem, but it seems your `fileStream` is not connected to any `account` in the loop.  It might be better to put the loop inside the `using` statement, rather than initializing and disposing the var `fileStream` every time around the `foreach` loop.

Comment: What does `InputOnlineFile` do to the file stream? Your code shown doesn't read the file anywhere...

Comment: @SeanSkelly I did this, but then the file is sent once, and then the execution drops out

Comment: As @SeanSkelly  mentioned the foreach should be inside the using statement. Did you check what InputOnlineFile does? Maybe InputOnlineFile closing the stream which is causing the execution to drop.

Comment: it just crossed my mind,  if If InputOnlineFile is not closing the stream then try ```fileStream.Position = 0;``` before calling botClient.SendVoiceAsync.

Stream is liner reading so once stream is read the position of the stream will be at the end and subsequent reads need the position to be set to 0.

Comment: @RameshKanjinghat Yes it is, it closes the stream

Comment: If memory is not a concern copy the file stream to memory stream before each loop. You have to set the stream position to 0 before copying.